# A Way to stop Firebase queueing

Tags: firebase

Suppose client 1 has:

```
messagesRef = new Firebase('https://yvv2pmvobjc.firebaseio-demo.com/');
messagesRef.on('child_changed',
               function (data, prev) { alert ("Changed " + data.val()); } ); `
```

Suppose client 2 has:

```
messagesRef = new Firebase('https://yvv2pmvobjc.firebaseio-demo.com/');
Firebase.goOffline();
item = messagesRef.child('baz'); 
item.set("1");
item.set("2");
item.set("3");
Firebase.goOnline();
```

This code will produce notifcations with *Change 1*, *Change 2* and *Change 3*. I want it to simply return *Change 3* and not process the intermediate steps. I'd prefer client 1 to never even send the intermediate steps to the remote Firebase at all. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you'd have to modify the Firebase JS source to pull that off. Though I'd recommend instead of that, refactor your code so that you store all of the intermediate steps in local objects and only ever call item.set() with the final state you actually want to store in Firebase.

Comment: Note that other clients will not always see the intermediate steps. Firebase only guarantees that the final result is correct (though in many cases it does send intermediate steps). On example is that if the other client lost its internet connection for a bit and then came back online, it would not get the intermediate events.

Comment: @AndrewLee that's exactly the situation I was trying to test by using goOffline. So Firebase behaves differently if it is offline due to an explicit call vs a failed connection?

Comment: @z4ce - I believe it behaves the same, even if you lose your internet connection the Firebase api will queue commands to send to the Firebase servers once a connection is re-established. The difference you're thinking of is based on what side of the equation you're on - sending data to Firebase or receiving data from Firebase. I'm running low on room in comments so I'll post info in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment and expanding on Andrew's..

Suppose you have two clients A and B. Client B is in charge of updating "Baz" while A is just listening. There are a few scenarios to consider.

Client A and B are both connected - B updates "Baz" several times, A receives all of these updates in near real-time.

Client A remains online but B goes offline (the scenario outlined in your code) - A still has its connection to Firebase so it's waiting for updates. B is offline so the updates to "Baz" are queued by the local Firebase scripts. B goes online and it fires off the updates to Firebase. A is still online and listening, so it receives all of these updates in near real-time.

Client A goes offline while B remains online. B updates "Baz" several times. The final value of "Baz" is "4" and a little while later, A goes online. When A goes online, Firebase is only going to send it the latest value of Baz since A was not online and listening when the intermediate updates were happening.

Finally, if both client A and B are offline then B will queue up its updates, and it really depends on which one goes online first to figure out what happens. In this scenario, it morphs into one of the other scenarios.

Comment: This is essentially correct given our current implementation. Note that we don't actually guarantee that every intermediate state will be sent even in the first case, even that's generally what we do right now.

Comment: So @AndrewLee , how about giving us some control over this? It wouldn't think it would be a hard feature to add. I'm not sure why, if the intermediate steps aren't guaranteed, to even bother with them at all.

Comment: It would break the abstraction we provide. We're not a messaging / eventing service -- we're a sync service. You shouldn't build apps that depend on specific eventing behavior of Firebase, as it may change as we find better ways to optimize things. Have your app depend only on the state and not how it got there.

We're working on making these optimizations as quick as we can, but it's hard work! If what you need is a messaging / eventing solution with very specific network behavior, Firebase might not be the right solution for you.

Comment: @z4ce - what if you only maintained the intermediate steps locally? If your downstream clients don't care about them, and you don't want them to see each step, then wait until you've finished your calculations/transforms to set the data in Firebase. It seems pretty easy to do since it seems like you know when your steps are complete. If you're worried about a system going down in the middle of calculations, you could always perform intermediate calculations at a different Firebase location /temp/baz but have your clients listen on /ready/baz. Only set on /ready/baz when done

Comment: @AndrewLee -- Indeed! A sync is exactly what I want. I don't want events for every step between the states. I don't see how having an option controlling the way the queueing works on the sync process breaks the abstraction. If anything, I think the current model of queuing intermediate steps breaks the abstraction. As people build Firebase apps, who knows how many will rely on this queueing synchronization behavior?

Comment: @MikePugh It's little bit more complicated that that. In my case I'm handling location updates and I want all clients to have the most recent location. I am retrieving a location every second or so. So if the firebase goes offline, memory usage goes up.. after significant portion of time passes, it starts to build up a sizable queue. When it finally gets a connection it floods all of the other clients with location updates and transmits far more data than I need (only the latest update). Of course.. I could workaround by detecting connection changes, but then I'm breaking the abstraction.

Comment: How does it break the abstraction for you to check connection changes? It seems like you'd have a service with an updateLocation method, and that updateLocation method could very cleanly throw away backend writes when offline (ie, if(_online) { _fb.set(location); }). This keeps your calling code in the dark about Firebase as well as the whole online/offline stuff. I would agree though that if the Firebase JS SDK provided a flag fb.enableOfflineQueue which defaults to true, then in certain cases like yours it'd be handy to disable. Though even with a flag like that, I'd wrap w/ a service.